# Layout resize on keyboard open in fullscreen mode only

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'd been trying to maintain consistency in `layout` whether keyboard is open or not. These issue is generated in `FULLSCREEN` Mode (hiding top notification bar) only. It works like a charm without `Fullscreen`.

Tried:

1. Added `android:softWindowMode="adjustResize"` and `android:softWindowMode="adjustPan"`inside `<activity>` of Manifest File.
2. Added `android:isScrollableContainer="false"` inside by top layout with `blue background` having `first`, `next`,`prev`,`last` symbol.

Desired Layout:

1. Top Layout `Blue Background` should never get hide whether keyboard is open or not.

These issue get resolved with `ActionBar` but it requires a lot of turn work which I don't intent to.

[image: Without Keyboard open] [image: On scrolling with keyboard work like a charm][image: on keyboard open distort my layout].

Is there any way other than `ActionBar` which resolve my issue?

Comment: Suggestion : Just a suggestion : if you set custom view of the Action bar as your layout, then you don't have to do any change in your code/logic. And you would still get the desired outcome.

Comment: @Swayam : Your suggestion would absolutely work likes a charm. But i tried not to use it as more of turn around work in many more `Activity`'s

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a fixed header layout for the blue back ground layout, and below this blue layout create a layout for other fields inside the `ScrollView` ...so that when keyboard appeared it will not hide the header blue layout...